# How to display holiday in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a calendar application in Java and have successfully completed the calendar display part. Now, I need to display Holiday messages below the calendar entries.

For example, if the calendar is displaying April month then "1 April - April Fool Day." will show.

Can anybody tell me how to do that? Here's my code:

```
    import java.time.Month;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class SwingCalendar extends JFrame {
     private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
       private JLabel statusLabel;
       private JPanel controlPanel;
       private JLabel msglabel;

  DefaultTableModel model;
  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
  JLabel label;

  SwingCalendar() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Swing Calandar");
    this.setSize(300,200);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);


    label = new JLabel();
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Back");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        updateMonth();
      }
    });

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Next");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
        updateMonth();
      }
    });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(b1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(b2,BorderLayout.EAST);


    String [] columns = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(null,columns);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

    this.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.updateMonth();

  }

  void updateMonth() {
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    String month = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    label.setText(month + " " + year);

    int startDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int numberOfDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int weeks = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

    model.setRowCount(0);
    model.setRowCount(weeks);

    int i = startDay-1;
    for(int day=1;day<=numberOfDays;day++){
      model.setValueAt(day, i/7 , i%7 );    
      i = i + 1;
    }

    }


  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    SwingCalendar sc = new SwingCalendar();    

  }

  private void showJPanelDemo(){
      headerLabel.setText("Container in action: JPanel");      
      msglabel = new JLabel("Welcome to TutorialsPoint SWING Tutorial.", JLabel.CENTER);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());        
      panel.add(msglabel);

      controlPanel.add(panel);        
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);      
   }   

}
```

Comment: I guess *The Medium is the Massage*.

Comment: I would imagine you would need one or more "events" models, which contain information about the event (like the day/date what ever measure you need) and the description

Comment: What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, people have tried using [JollyDay Calendar](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net)

You may want to check this and use the relevant API. You can setup specific holiday calendars using XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you design a data structure for your holidays. There are several options. A simple options is a two-dimentional array of Strings where a String represents a holiday and null represents "not a holiday". I may or may not be enough for your requirements.

Inside your loop you make a lookup into your data structure. If a holiday is found, you do something like `model.setValueAt(day + " " + holiday, i/7 , i%7);` If you need more guidance, please add a comment.